# python: brentq optimization within optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm having some extremely annoying problems with my code.
I think my problem is that under the minimal wall thickness part (wtMIN) i'm calculating an optimum within an optimum. Th answer converges to a certain value but within that conversion the zero which is required fro brentq to function moves away drom the calculation boundaries.

```
 def wtMIN(self,diameter):
    '''
    #here the minimum required wallthickness is calculated for a given diameter
    #Firstly the minimum diameter required to overcome stresses is calculated
    #Since inertia increases to the power of 4 this optimisation always leads to 
    #very large diameter and very small wall thickness, this causes the structure
    #to buckle.
    #Therefore a bucking check is done to see if the structure would buckle
    #Under de BuckOk check. If the structure would buckle a smaller diameter is
    #used and the buckling calculation is made again up untill a diameter and wall
    #thickness if found were no buckling occurs.
    #This buckling optimization cant be done with an optimizer since the
    #function is not contintous.
    '''
    try:
        diameter=diameter[0]
    except TypeError:
        diameter=diameter
    D=diameter
    wt=brentq(self.stressRATIO,D/10000,D/3,args=(D),xtol=0.001)
    buckOK = 'False'
    while buckOK == 'False':
        buckOK=self.buckcheck(D,wt)
        if buckOK == 'False':
            D=D-0.01
            wt=brentq(self.stressRATIO,D/10000,D/3,args=(D),xtol=0.001)
    return wt
```

Again, i think the problem here is that the D=D-01 loop which wants to find the minimum buckling diameter causes the optimum to shift outside the brentq ranges (I get a value error that  f(a) and f(b) need to have different signs.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this? It's been busting my balls for more that four weeks now :(

Thanx

Comment: If you get that value error, it is because your range `(D/10000, D/3)` is not a "sign changing interval". That means you shouldn't have decreased `D` by .01, which in turn means that your `buckcheck` should have returned "True". The problem lies in your algorithm then (and so in the part of your code that you didn't show). One hint: python has Boolean variables `True` and `False`. You are using strings to have the same effect, but it's not as convenient.

Comment: Hi oliver, thanks for the comment. I'll try to find a new solution with your answer.